# Upgrade org.springframework.boot 1.4.2. RELEASE to 1.5.9 RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just tried to upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent from **1.4.2** to **1.5.9**
and my application failed to start with this issue.
I tried to solve it, but `AbstractBeanFactoryclass` 363th row wasn't helpful. :(

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)

---

**UPDATE:**

*It seems the bad guy is @ConditionalOnProperty, but i am not sure.*

This is what i was able to get by 'Watches':

https://pastebin.com/y1Jxm3it

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace please?

Comment: Show us the content of the class AbstractBeanFactoryclass.

Comment: Configure a `LocaleResolver` apparently you have configured things in such a way that (part) of the auto configuration isn't working anymore.

Comment: I shared the whole stack trace by pastebin.

Comment: @Dherik AbstractBeanFactory class belongs to org.springframework.beans.factory.support